# Copying value from one column to another if it includes certain value

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

[image]

Original Image .. http://screencast.com/t/jk3IIbuuV

Need to grab 5 types of data from a row of ~500 and paste into 5 separate rows.  Ideally the data would be transformed as shown to the right of the screenshot.

1. Name of clinic
2. Clinic email address
3. Website
4. Name of representative
5. Type of clinic

I'm thinking some type of If formula/macro which searches for capitals, another which searches for @ and returns the string, another which searches for www, and another which searches for a bullet point.  Possible?

Comment: Cell A2 has `@` and `www` on same string without spaces. Is this pattern common on your 500 rows data?

Comment: This seam to be a copy-paste from web browser. Instead of copy-paste, have you tried open URL in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you just gave a little bit rows of your 500 hundreds so I assumed some patterns:

I think I got the "Name of Clinic", "Website" and "E-mail",

Data is on column `A`.
Examples will be shown for one cell, but formulas are reproducible for other cells (just drag them).

**Name of clinic.**

Convert all strings in upper case strings.

```
B1 =UPPER(A1)
```

Check if the new string (B1) is different from the original one (A1).

```
C1 =IF(EXACT(A1,B1),A1,"")
```

**Website**

Track character position of: "www."

```
B1 =SEARCH("www.",A1,1)
```

Crop string after "www."

```
C1 =MID(A1,B1,100)
```

Track character position of: ".cl" *(assuming all examples you gave had websites finishing only with ".cl")*.

```
D1 =SEARCH(".cl",C1,1)
```

Replace everything at right of ".cl" (just in case the string does not finish in ".cl"), for ".cl" only.

```
E1 =REPLACE(C1,D1,100,".cl")
```

**E-mail**

The same idea as website, but now, making stronger assumptions about the raw data:
- all phone numbers have the format (2) XXXX XXXX or (2) XXXX-XXXX;
- the e-mail information is right away on the right of the phone number.

```
B1 =FIND("(2)",A1,1)  
C1 =MID(A1,B1,100)  
D1 =MID(K18,14,100) #remove the phone number (13 characters)#  
E1 =SEARCH(".cl",L18,1)  
F1 =REPLACE(D1,E1,100,".cl")
```

I did not try to gather the "Type of Clinic", because I could not reproduce the bullet on Excel (actually, I copied and pasted bullets from MS Word, but I am not sure if it was the same data format as yours). My first attempt would be to use the formula `B1 =left(A1,1)`, to extract the first character of each string. Probably there will be a pattern (same character) for all text/strings with bullet. Then, one would just filter the cells selecting the bullet character and copy/past "Type of Clinic" information.

I have no idea about how to retrieve the "Contact Name", but with the suggestions I proposed here it would be possible to eliminate the rows with information of "Type of Clinic" and "Name of Clinic".